# Apache hosting Flask Cannot see Docker Environment Variables

Tags: python, apache, docker, flask

My Flask app cannot see environment variables set in docker-compose, but python in the container can. Any ideas on how I can get Flask to see them as well? I think it's a problem with Apache not passing the environment variable, but I can't seem to get it to pass.

This error shows up when I start the apache webserver inside the docker container:

```
Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2[Tue Jun 16 23:12:00.810164 2020] [env:warn] [pid 1311:tid 139882286290048] AH01506: PassEnv variable TEST was undefined
```

I'm defining my environment variable in a docker compose, like this:

```
ai:
image: ai:dev
environment:
  TEST: test
```

Then I grab the OS environ object in code and output it and get this:

```
environ({'APACHE_RUN_DIR': '/var/run/apache2', 'APACHE_PID_FILE': '/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid', 'PATH': '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin', 'APACHE_LOCK_DIR': '/var/lock/apache2', 'LANG': 'C', 'APACHE_RUN_USER': 'www-data', 'APACHE_RUN_GROUP': 'www-data', 'APACHE_LOG_DIR': '/var/log/apache2', 'PWD': '/'})
```

If I go into the container and load up python and try I get this:

```
environ({'HOSTNAME': 'd3ce1f616cad', 'PYTHON_VERSION': '3.8.2', 'PWD': '/app', 'HOME': '/root', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'GPG_KEY': 'E3FF2839C048B25C084DEBE9B26995E310250568', 'PYTHONPATH': ':/app', 'TERM': 'xterm', 'SHLVL': '1', 'PYTHON_PIP_VERSION': '20.0.2', 'PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256': '421ac1d44c0cf9730a088e337867d974b91bdce4ea2636099275071878cc189e', 'PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL': 'https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/d59197a3c169cef378a22428a3fa99d33e080a5d/get-pip.py', 'PATH': '/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin', 'TEST': 'test', '_': '/usr/local/bin/python'})
```

The test variable is there.

Why can python in the container see the variable but my flask app in the same container cannot? Here's the wsgi and conf files if they will help:

ai.wsgi:

```
`#!/usr/bin/python3.8
import sys
import logging
import os

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/ai/")

from ai import app as application`
```

ai.conf:

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName 192.168.1.103
                ServerAdmin admin@tsames.ca
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ai/ai.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/ai/ai/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ai-error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ai-access.log combined
                PassEnv TEST
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hum..that is odd. Try defining your environment variable as: - TEST=test (including the dash). That is how I usually define them. See if that works.

Comment: I gave that a go and at first it said the format was invalid. I had to do it this way -"TEST=test". It works the same as mine did. Environment Variable is visible in the container and can be accessed by the running python process, but cannot be accessed by apache. Passing it in results in the same error as before, says it's undefined. Behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured this out. More googling later and I stumbled across [this post](https://medium.com/@william.b/setting-dynamic-environmental-variables-in-apache-from-the-os-1d5c1e2e9e6c) that explains what to do.

The short version for my scenario above:
The problem is the environment variables aren't available to apache2 to pass into the WSGI session. They can't be put in the conf file as it doesn't have access to bash. The solution is to add this line to the evironment file at /etc/environment:

```
/etc/environment:
export TEST=${TEST}
```

Next, add this to /etc/apache2/envvars to link the environment file up to apache, it has access to bash so it'll work:

```
/etc/apache2/envvars:
... (Default file stuff)
. /etc/environment
```

Lastly, in the conf file you'd put in (as I did above):

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ai.conf:
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName 192.168.1.103
                ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ai/ai.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/ai/ai/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ai-error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ai-access.log combined
                PassEnv TEST
</VirtualHost>
```

Note the PassEnv, which will work now that apache has access to the environment variables. Also, a fun note: remember to escape special characters in the environment variables or weird problems will crop up!